# How to install dependencies in OpenShift?

Tags: python, openshift

Hello i want to install these dependencies in OpenShift for my App

`yum -y install wget gcc zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel libffi-devel libxslt libxslt-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel openldap-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel openjpeg-devel libtiff-devel libyaml-devel python-virtualenv git libpng12 libXext xorg-x11-font-utils`

But don't know how, is it through rhc? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the "yum" command to install packages on OpenShift.  What specific issue are you having? I am sure that at least some of those packages are already installed in OpenShift online already (such as wget).  Have you tried running your project to see what specific errors you get about what is missing?

Comment: I'm trying to install Odoo 8 (OpenErp) in Openshift but can't even load the setup page on it, i already clone the git and added the files but can't get it to load... i get the 404 page "The requested URL / was not found on this server." just like if it doesn't read the files...

Answer (score 0):

The lib libjpeg and others is already installed on Open Shift, just create the symlinks:

```
> ln -s /usr/lib64/libz.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/ ln -s
> /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/ ln -s
> /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/
```

Look for others libs installed on /usr/lib64 if they are not already installed and create the links